# Words that mean ''to inadvertently say something''

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Like when you're talking and inadvertently say something and then realize it.

Comment: One might *blurt out* nonsense or insults before ones brain engages.

Comment: You might "give something away" that is supposed to be a secret.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean please? Do you mean accidentally using the wrong word, or giving away information which you were not supposed to share?

Comment: @Spagirl I think he means accidentally using the wrong word or like saying something tactless,foolish,etc accidentally. I don't think its giving away information

Comment: ***blab, misspeak, let slip, let the cat out of the bag, spill the beans,...*** What's the exact intended meaning?

Comment: I kinda favor "speako".

Comment: Perhaps a [**slip of the tongue**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/slip_of_the_tongue).

Answer (score 1):

1. [**Freudian Slip**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Freudian%20slip) or [**Parapraxis**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parapraxis) - "[an error in speech, memory, or physical action that occurs due to the interference of an unconscious subdued wish or internal train of thought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudian_slip)"
2. [**Blunder**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blunder) - "to utter stupidly, confusedly, or thoughtlessly", "to make a stupid, careless, or thoughtless mistake in"
3. [**Misspeak**](http://to%20express%20(oneself)%20imperfectly%20or%20incorrectly) - "to express (oneself) imperfectly or incorrectly"
4. [**Let it slip**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20slip) - "to say (something that one did not want to say) by mistake"
5. **[To give away](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/give-away), [a dead giveaway](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead%20giveaway)** - ex: 1) *Whoops, I gave away the answer.* 2) *The look on his face was a dead giveaway*
6. [**Divulge**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/divulge) - "make known (private or sensitive information)"
7. [**Blurt Out**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blurt--out) - "to utter suddenly or inadvertently; divulge impulsively or unadvisedly"

These are all words that could be used in the manner you described, depending on the context. If you give us an example sentence we may be able to help you out further :)

Comment: What about ''Blurt out'' doesn't it mean to say something inadvertently?

Comment: @DanielRigg excellent suggestion, I've added that to the answer